# What are some good, free data modeler programs available for Linux that work with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: database, linux, database-design, data-modeling

I am looking for some good, free data modeler programs for Linux that are painless to install and work with SQLAlchemy. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744097/open-source-data-modeler

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76350/free-cheap-powerdesigner-alternative

Comment: Does "painless to install" include invoking your package manager? What about `.configure && make && sudo make install`?

Comment: "painless to install" isn't a real requirement. that's in the same class as "fast as possible"

Comment: Stephanie Page, I edited my question to be more specific. dmckee right well, it would be nice. perhaps i am jsut scared of the command line. i'm working on it bit by bit. the `.configure && make && sudo make install` is scary but i am open to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dia and Dia2SQLAlchemy (http://code.google.com/p/dia2sqlalchemy/)

Dia comes standard on many Linux distros and works well enough.  It's an open source tool aimed roughly at the Visio market though not nearly as polished as Visio is.